# Silex optional slug in route

Tags: regex, symfony, routes, silex

I've constructed a URL in Silex to match `/tutorial` or `/tutorial/index` or `/tutorial/pageX` where X is a number, but I'd also like it to match `/tutorial/` and I'm struggling to make that happen. This is the route I have so far:

```
$app->get('/tutorial/{page}', 'app\\Controller\\Tutorial::index')
    ->assert('page', '(^(page[\d]+|index)$|^$)')
    ->value('page', 'index');
```

If I try that [regex in regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/hT0qL5/2) it works, having nothing there matches. So why doesn't it work in Silex and what can I use that will work?

Appologies if this is a duplicate but all my searches turned up similar things, but not this exact situation where the whole string must match or be nothing.

Comment: Can you please check if this is what you want? https://regex101.com/r/rT4qK3/1? Else, please clarify what the input strings can be and what you want the output to look like.

Comment: That's the output I want, but `/tutorial/` shouldn't be in the regex, as the regex is only for the `{page}` value. I want `{page}` to either be `pageX` where `X` is a number, or `index`, or nothing at all. I'm not sure how else to clarify that. Are you familiar with routing in symfony / silex?

Comment: I have a general idea of what you are trying to do. `page` is a variable, and you try to valiate it with `assert`, and you also set `index` as its default value. If `^(page\d+|index|)$` does not work in the current code, try not using `value` together with `assert`, pass the "index" value in a query, and see if it works then. And try using `'app\Controller\Tutorial::index'`.

Comment: Almost, the `value` method sets `{page}` to `index` if the URL is `/tutorial`. If the URL is `/tutorial/a_value` then it matches the value against the regex, and if it passes calls the `app\Controller\Tutorial::index` method, passing in `a_value` as the variable `$page`. If the value doesn't match the regex it throws an error,

Comment: So, did you try `->value('page', '');` with the updated regex? Do you get the expected behavior? If not, I guess the issue is with the Tutorial::index method that cannot handle empty match.

Comment: The updated regex won't work, it includes `/tutorial/` in it, which it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

`^(page\d+|index|)$`

It will match "page*n*", "index", or "".

If you still do not achieve what you need, I guess the issue is with the `app\Controller\Tutorial::index` method that cannot handle empty match.